# I want to get multiple count from same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with details of user orders, I want a total number of orders, and the number of orders in last month and number of orders in last week.

Table structure

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id             | bigint(21 ) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| customer_id    | bigint(21)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| provider_id    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| order_datetime | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pickup_datetime| date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status         | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table data

```
[{"id": 1,"customer_id": 1,"provider_id": 2,"order_datetime": "2016-11-24 14:52:51","pickup_datetime": "2016-11-24 14:53:19","status": 3}, {"id": 2,"customer_id": 1,"provider_id": 2,"order_datetime": "2016-11-24 15:18:30","pickup_datetime": "2016-11-24 15:18:36","status": 3}, {"id": 3,"customer_id": 1,"provider_id": 2,"order_datetime": "2016-11-24 17:19:27","pickup_datetime": "2016-11-24 17:19:33","status": 3}, {"id": 4,"customer_id": 0,"provider_id": 2,"order_datetime": "2016-11-24 17:30:46","pickup_datetime": "2016-11-24 17:30:51","status": 3}, {"id": 5,"customer_id": 1,"provider_id": 2,"order_datetime": "2016-11-24 17:37:52","pickup_datetime": "2016-11-24 17:38:00","status": 3}, {"id": 6,"customer_id": 1,"provider_id": 2,"order_datetime": "2016-11-25 11:31:51","pickup_datetime": "2016-11-25 11:32:14","status": 3}, {"id": 7,"customer_id": 1,"provider_id": 2,"order_datetime": "2016-11-25 11:36:05","pickup_datetime": "2016-11-25 11:36:16","status": 3}, {"id": 8,"customer_id": 1,"provider_id": 2,"order_datetime": "2016-11-25 11:41:10","pickup_datetime": "2016-11-25 11:41:17","status": 3}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you showed no table structure, data, or effort.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in a single pass over the order table using conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW()
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS last_week_cnt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS last_month_cnt,
    COUNT(*) AS all_cnt
FROM orders
```

This should outperform the UNION approach.  Note that if a given record in your table could correspond to more than one order, and there is a column for that, then we could slightly modify my query to sum this column instead of defaulting to one order per record.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "all orders", count(*) FROM Orders
UNION ALL
SELECT "last month", count(*) FROM Orders WHERE orderdate BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and now();
UNION ALL
SELECT "last week", count(*) FROM Orders WHERE orderdate BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();
```

Comment: I suggest UNION ALL, and some value telling which count it is.

Answer (score 0):

A you can combine the 3 different queries will give you what you are looking for
(total number of orders query)'Total Orders', (the number of orders in last month query)'order count', (number of orders in last week query)'order count last week'